# Comparar 2 Matrizes e Retornar uma Terceira (R)

Tags: r, matriz, comparação

Sendo as seguintes matrizes

***Matriz(A)***

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] 0.228 0.285 0.285 0.285 0.380
[2,] 0.228 0.285 0.570 0.380 0.228
[3,] 0.380 0.285 0.228 0.380 0.285
[4,] 0.285 0.285 0.570 0.380 0.380
[5,] 0.380 0.228 0.285 0.285 0.380
```

***Matriz(B)***

```
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,] 0.383 0.174 0.535 0.700 0.396
[2,] 0.404 0.785 0.346 0.838 0.074
[3,] 0.591 0.554 0.260 0.229 0.361
[4,] 0.176 0.865 0.423 0.166 0.349
[5,] 0.132 0.018 0.456 0.684 0.150
```

Como eu consigo retornar uma terceira ***Matriz(C)*** que retorna 1 se o valor na mesma posição da ***Matrix(B)*** for menor ou igual do que o da ***Matriz(A)*** e 0 se for maior ?

A Matrix(C) Resultante seria

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,]  0     1     0     0     0
[2,]  0     0     1     0     1
[3,]  0     0     0     1     0
[4,]  1     0     1     1     1
[5,]  1     1     0     0     1
```

Comment: Acabei fazendo um exemplo minimo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Resposta

```r
C <- ifelse(B <= A, 1, 0)
```

### Explicação

O operador `<=` é *vetorizado*: ele retorna o resultado da comparação (`TRUE` ou `FALSE`) entre elementos correspondentes dos vetores ou matrizes comparados. Portanto, `B <= A` retorna uma matriz de `TRUE` e `FALSE` do mesmo tamanho de `A` e de `B`. Resultado:

```r
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
[1,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

A função `ifelse` troca os valores `TRUE` de um vetor ou matriz pelo segundo argumento (no exemplo, `1`) e os valores `FALSE` pelo terceiro argumento (no exemplo, `0`).

### Solução alternativa

Solução mais econômica porém mais esotérica:

```r
C <- (B <= A) + 0
```

(a soma é um truque para converter a matriz de booleanos para matriz de inteiros)

Comment: Nossa que legal, eu não sou programador em `R`, parabéns ...

Comment: Acho que essa é a forma mais elegante e rápida para o problema.

Comment: Excelente, melhor que isso impossivel.

Comment: Muito muito muito bom!

Answer (score 1):

***Codificação:***

```cs
# CRIAÇÃO DAS VARIAVEIS DE MATRIZ
A <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5);
B <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5);
C <- matrix(1:25, 5, 5);

# SETANDO OS VALORES DA MATRIZ A
A[1,1] = 0.228; A[1,2] = 0.285; A[1,3] = 0.285; A[1,4] = 0.285; A[1,5] = 0.380;
A[2,1] = 0.228; A[2,2] = 0.285; A[2,3] = 0.570; A[2,4] = 0.380; A[2,5] = 0.228;
A[3,1] = 0.380; A[3,2] = 0.285; A[3,3] = 0.228; A[3,4] = 0.380; A[3,5] = 0.285;
A[4,1] = 0.285; A[4,2] = 0.285; A[4,3] = 0.570; A[4,4] = 0.380; A[4,5] = 0.380;
A[5,1] = 0.380; A[5,2] = 0.228; A[5,3] = 0.285; A[5,4] = 0.285; A[5,5] = 0.380;


# SETANDO OS VALORES DA MATRIZ B
B[1,1] = 0.383; B[1,2] = 0.174; B[1,3] = 0.535; B[1,4] = 0.700; B[1,5] = 0.396;
B[2,1] = 0.404; B[2,2] = 0.785; B[2,3] = 0.346; B[2,4] = 0.838; B[2,5] = 0.380;
B[3,1] = 0.591; B[3,2] = 0.554; B[3,3] = 0.260; B[3,4] = 0.229; B[3,5] = 0.361;
B[4,1] = 0.176; B[4,2] = 0.865; B[4,3] = 0.423; B[4,4] = 0.166; B[4,5] = 0.349;
B[5,1] = 0.132; B[5,2] = 0.018; B[5,3] = 0.456; B[5,4] = 0.684; B[5,5] = 0.150;

i <- 1;
j <- 1;

#Como eu consigo retornar uma terceira 
#Matriz (C) que retorna 1 se o valor na mesma 
#posicao da matrix B for menor ou igual do que o da 
#matriz(A) e 0 se for maior ?

while(i < 6)
{
   j <- 1;
   while(j < 6){
      C[i,j] <- 1;
      if (A[i,j] <= B[i,j]){
         C[i,j] <- 0; 
      }
      j <- j + 1;
   }
   i <- i + 1;
}

#MOSTRANDO VALORES RESULTADOS DA MATRIZ C 
C;
```

***Exemplo:*** [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/Mty5a8)

*Referências:*

- [R for Beginners](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Paradis-rdebuts_en.pdf)
- [While Loop](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/programming-in-r#TOC-For-Loop)